# Writing multiple on conditions in self join in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm unable to write this sql query into linq.can any body please help.thanks in advance

```
 select catp.Name from Article art join Categorys cat on art.CategoryId=cat.CategoryId join Categorys catp
 on cat.ParentCategoryId=catp.CategoryId or cat.CategoryId = catp.CategoryId where ArticleId=24
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have given is bit confusing. Why you have joined Categorys catp and wrote joining condition "or cat.CategoryId = catp.CategoryId". It will give u the same result as below query:

```
select cat.Name from Article art 
join Categorys cat on art.CategoryId=cat.CategoryId 
where ArticleId=24
```

It should be now simple to write a Linq on above query. If wants to filter items where ParentCategoryId=CategoryId in Categorys, then it should be:

```
select cat.Name from Article art 
join Categorys cat on art.CategoryId=cat.CategoryId 
where ArticleId=24 and cat.ParentCategoryId = cat.CategoryId
```

Linq:

```
var result = (from cat in Categories
                join art in Articals
                    on cat.CategoryId equals art.CategoryId
                where art.CategoryId == 24 && cat.CategoryId == cat.ParentCategoryId
                select cat.Name).ToList()
```